# Matching data from Child table below a date, which is in main table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have data in two tables

Table:Sub_Data

```
+----------------+-----------------------+
|  SKU_No        | SKU_Registration_Date |
+----------------+-----------------------+
| abc123         | 1/21/2016             |
| abc124         | 2/21/2016             |
| xyz124         | 3/1/2016              |
+----------------+-----------------------+
```

Table: SKU_Rate

```
+--------+----------+------+
| SKU_NO | Eff_Date | Rate |
+--------+----------+------+
| abc123 | 1/1/2016 |   25 |
| abc123 | 2/1/2016 |   27 |
| abc123 | 3/1/2016 |   29 |
| abc124 | 1/1/2016 |   35 |
| abc124 | 2/1/2016 |   37 |
| abc124 | 3/1/2016 |   39 |
| xyz124 | 1/1/2016 |   45 |
| xyz124 | 2/1/2016 |   47 |
| xyz124 | 3/1/2016 |   49 |
+--------+----------+------+
```

I would like to have a Query, should return for Sub_Data effective rate from SKU_Rate

Sample output should be like this

```
SKU_No  SKU_Registration_Date   Rate

abc123  1/21/2016                25 as this rate is effective till 2/1/2016 -1 day

abc124  2/21/2016                39 as this rate is effective till 3/1/2016 - 1 day

xyz124  3/1/2016                 49 as this rate is effective from 3/1/2016
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to join the `SKU_Rate` twice (using two different aliases). The first join will be

```
ON Sub_Data.SKU_No=SKU_Rate.SKU_NO AND SKU_Rate.Eff_Date<=Sub_Data.SKU_Registration_Date
```

and from that you will get `MAX(Eff_Date)` and `Rate`

The other join will be

```
ON Sub_Data.SKU_No=SKU_Rate.SKU_NO AND SKU_Rate.Eff_Date>Sub_Data.SKU_Registration_Date
```

and from that you will get `MIN(Eff_Date)`

That will give you the two dates to generate the result you want, with the use of IIFs and the two dates (and checking for potential null dates).